# MVC 5 Authentication uses Twitter Pin-Based OAuth

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, twitter-oauth, owin, katana

I'm new to MVC Authentication, so I'm working on a sample project to get familiar with using external authentication.  I've got Facebook and Google working, but I'm having trouble with Twitter.

I can get to Twitter's log-in page, but instead of redirecting back to my application like Facebook and Google does, it just displays a Pin and says I need to go back to my application and enter the Pin.  It appears that the middle-ware is using [Pin-Based authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/pin-based).  Any tips for setting it up so that it doesn't use Pin-Based?

My application is MVC 5, .net 4.5.1, EF6, and Authentication 2.0.

Inside Startup.Auth, I've uncommented app.UseTwitterAuthentication and provided the comsumer key and secret provided by Twitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just deleting the app in Twitter and creating a new one, which works correctly.

When I initially created the first app, I had left the Callback URL empty.  When testing with that configuration, I couldn't get to the Login screen, I just kept getting a 401 error.  Once I added a callback url, I started getting to the login screen, but it was using the Pin-Based.

I thought that I had configured something incorrectly during the setup process, so that's why I deleted the application (in Twitter) and created a new one.  In my project, I just changed the key and secret.  There was no option during setup to select pin-based, but I did create it with a callback url.

I did create a third application (in Twitter) with no callback url, in an attempt to duplicate the problem, but I was unable to duplicate.